# I get a cors error when using axios to send form

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, axios

What's the equivalent axios code for this:

```
<form method='post' action='https://sample.com' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

I tried the following

```
const bodyFormData = new FormData();
        bodyFormData.set('name', inputData.name);
        bodyFormData.set('hush_sender', inputData.email);
        bodyFormData.set('subject', inputData.subject);
        bodyFormData.set('message', inputData.message);

        const response = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `https://sample.com`,
            data: bodyFormData,
            config: {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }
        });
```

But I get the following error when using axios:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sample.com' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

(I don't have control over mydomain.com. That is a third party api. They sent the code in the html form, but I want to use axios.)

Comment: @Quentin So there's no way I can prevent the navigation to the new page?

Comment: If you own sample.com then you can provide cors headers. You can also configure a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) if you are using create-react-app

Comment: @HMR I don't own it... That's why I can't use cors.. I think

Comment: If it's just for testing you can add a chrome plugin that wil allow CORS

Comment: @HMR I need this for production....

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do. CORS are enforced by the browser so other sites cannot just use your API's. If it wasn't that way then anyone can just use anyone's API's without permission.

Comment: Got it. Thank you @HMR !!!